# Max tablename length with registerTempTable in Python

Tags: python, pyspark

I am a absolute novice in python and this is a very basic question to which I could not find an answer while searching.

I am using **registerTempTable** function to register a dataframe as table, I wanted to check what is the max length there can be for the tablename? To test I used up to 70 characters and it did register the table, but for my own knowledge I wanted to know if there is any restriction on the length of the tablename.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please include your code so we can give you specific guidance as per [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with a HiveContext, then the max length of a table name should be the max length allowed by Hive/Metastore (last time I checked, were 128 characters), probably the same thing happen with SqlContext.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply.